# How do I make my discord bot have a custom status (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to find a way to update my bots status via discord.js

I've tried all over the web for solutions, but can't seem to find any.
I've looked all over StackOverflow etc.

Be aware I am running on discord.js V12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried all over the web for solutions, but can't seem to find any

Did you not look at the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org) website, where this solution is clearly documented and easily discoverable? I'd recommend looking there first when it comes to these types of questions.

I don't know what you mean by `status` (are you talking about idle/offline/online status or "Bot is playing x" status?), but I'm demonstrating simple examples of how to do both status and activity below. These examples are both taken directly from the discord.js docs.

**Status**

```
// Set the client user's status
client.user.setStatus('idle')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

**Activity**

```
// Set the client user's activity
client.user.setActivity('an activity', { type: 'PLAYING' })
  .then(presence => console.log(`Activity set to ${presence.activities[0].name}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

**Relevant Resources**
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setStatus 
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity

Comment: Hi Cannicide, 

I've implemented this into my code but I am getting a TypeError.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setStatus' of null

Comment: That means your `client` variable is undefined. Perhaps you named the variable `bot`? Look at the line of your code where you do `new Discord.Client()`, and use the name of the variable on that line. For example, if your code uses `bot.on("message")` instead of `client.on("message")`, replace `client` with `bot` in this answer's code and it will work for you.

Comment: Hi Cannicide, I have everything on "client.on" "new = Discord.Client()" ect.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.user.setActivity(`Hello World`, {type: 'PLAYING'});
```

or

```
client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: `Something`, type: "LISTENING" }, status: 'dnd' });
```

There are a lot of ways to do it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Jannik, Ive implemented this in my code.

But I am getting a Type Error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setStatus' of null

Comment: Hey make sure that the code that I gave you above is the only in relation to your bot's status. You are using `setStatus` elsewhere but I have not implemented anything with `setStatus`. Merry christmas btw ^^